# Integer Underflow weakness, using facebook Infer

Tags: java, static-analysis

This is a bad() function of one test case of Juliet test suite. As you can see that according to Juliet, there is a possible integer underflow in the 4th line from the end.
My question is: is that seems valid flaw? i.e a static analysis should detect it as an underflow weakness? because I see that facebook Infer could cot detect it.

```
public void bad() throws Throwable
  {
      int data;

      /* POTENTIAL FLAW: Use the maximum value for this type */
      data = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

      if(data < 0) /* ensure we won't have an overflow */
      {

      /* POTENTIAL FLAW: if (data * 2) < Integer.MIN_VALUE, this will underflow */
      int result = (int)(data * 2);
      IO.writeLine("result: " + result);
     }
  }
```

Comment: Did you contrive this example just for Stack Overflow? It doesn't seem like a good example. `data < 0` is always true so doesn't ensure anything, and `data * 2` is always 0, so doesn't underflow.

Comment: isn't it allowed to ask such question? why? it is an artificial test case actually! I did not build it by myself. Also,  -2147483648*2 does not give 0

Comment: No, I didn't say it was allowed. It's just that the results of the static analysis are clearly false positives